# Is there a way to set white balance of a RAW to match the preview JPEG?

Tags: raw, jpeg, white-balance, sony-nex, lightroom-5

When I view ARWs in Lightroom, I sometimes find the white balance of the embedded preview JPEG to be perfect, so I'd like to apply it to the RAW. How do that I do that in LR or other (free) software?

Here's an example. First, the [original ARW file](http://speedy.sh/3CZnz/DSC8592.ARW). And here's the preview JPEG, which accurately captured the color of the sunlight on the door:

[image]

(This is a screenshot of FastRawViewer, set to display the preview JPEG. I couldn't figure out how to tell FastRawViewer to save it as a JPEG, so I took a screenshot.)

In Lightroom, the photo has an orangish look — a warmer white balance:

[image]

So I changed the Color Calibration profile from "Adobe Standard" to "Camera Standard", which helped, but it still has too warm a white balance:

[image]

I then tried Sony's Image Data Converter, with the white balance set to "Camera Setting", assuming that it will be truer to the camera (Sony NEX-5R), but it was worse:

[image]

I'd like to apply the white balance in the JPEG to the RAW file. Is that possible in Lightroom, or with other free Mac software?

It would have helped if I'd shot RAW+JPEG, but I didn't, so I'm looking for a way to apply the white balance from the embedded JPEG to the RAW.

Comment: In Lr the effect of the white balance depends somewhat on a dcp profile you've chosen in Lr. Without an example of a raw file where you can see the issue it is difficult to see what is wrong, and by how much the white balance is off. Or even if it is white balance that is an issue.

Comment: I updated the question with this information. Thanks.

Comment: In Lr, you can switch from Adobe Standard to Camera Standard dcp (Camera Calibration), it will help a little. More accurate way to address the issue is to create a custom dcp profile. The culprit is not white balance, but the dcp profile. Adobe way of calculating white balance is very dependent on the dcp profile.

Comment: @IliahBorg - care to make that an answer? :)

Comment: @James Snell : But it is not an answer, as the procedure of creating an accurate dcp file is quite complicated and involves skills and equipment not generally available. For all practical purposes, the answer is "no" for a general case; and especially if we demand a very close match for a scene lit by anything relatively far from daylight/flash. There are some more and less well-behaved canned dcp, and click white balance tool usually results in acceptable match.

Comment: I updated the question with the photos. Lightroom's "Camera Standard" color calibration helped, but it still wasn't as good as the preview JPEG. Is the conclusion that isn't not easily possible to apply the white balance or the tone curves from the JPEG to the RAW?

Comment: Apparently not in the case of your Sony NEX. My Canon cameras all include the shot WB (What is applied to the preview image) in the maker notes section of the EXIF info.

Comment: Wild guess : if you have access to Photoshop, you could try the "Image => Adjustments => Match color" using the JPG as source and playing with the options. It won't change the white balance but it may help

Comment: Sorry, I don't have Photoshop, only Lightroom.

Comment: Use the manufacturers conversion tool - it will use the same presets as the camera. All other companies reverse engineer the format either entirely or to some degree and especially Adobe tends towards producing a warmer colour/look. (Capture One has finer control, though that may need work to get it to match perfectly.)

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I tried Sony's tool, and it was worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this many times with Lightroom.

Since "use camera white balance" is different from what your program shows, I would open (view) the "preview JPEG" and then use gcolor2 on linux or colorcop on windows to analyze the color values. Use the dropper to select what you perceive to be the best color. Copy those numbers to a textpad.

I would use that information to adjust the image in whatever program you are in whether it is lightroom, photoshop, ufraw, or gimp.

This would synchronize the the jpeg, that you see with your eyes, to what the program should be showing.

For the long term, I would consider icc, icm, color profiles and a monitor calibrating apparatus.

Since you are on a mac, here are some color picker program options:
https://bjango.com/mac/skalacolor/
http://www.robinwood.com/Catalog/Technical/OtherTuts/MacColorPicker/MacColorPicker.html

You can start with "use camera white balance" "daylight" or "Neutral" as starting points. Then go to "custom white balance" to make the adjustments.

Nikon and Canon still have color and contrast values in their RAW files. Fuji has pure RAW files.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken RAW is unprocessed. Therefore any balancing, sharpening, or noise reduction is not applied to it unlike a JPEG. You'll have to adjust the white balance in post production. Most editing programs will have it listed under white balance, cast, or temperature.

Comment: But that doesn't answer the question of *how* to do this editing such that the edited RAW file has the same white balance as the JPEG created by the camera.

Comment: The white balance of the JPEG might be in the EXIF data of the photo.

Comment: This brings me back to the problem I mentioned earlier, which is that I don't have a tool that can export the preview JPEG as a separate file. Do you know of one that runs on the Mac, with a GUI, and free?

Answer (score -2):

Okay you want to view Raw photos.

http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/rawviewer

http://www.fastrawviewer.com/download

Probably the first link is what you want.

Comment: The first link appears to be video viewing software - how is it relative to this question?  Isn't the point to be able to adjust WB in Lightroom?

Comment: Sorry wrong link. I thought sony-raw was about dslr.

This link discusses converting to dng for a more universal usage.
http://photographyconcentrate.com/2-useful-sony-nex-lightroom-tips/

Comment: This list shows all raw formats supported by all adobe products
https://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/kb/camera-raw-plug-supported-cameras.html


Fastrawviewer is dcraw based which claims to open all arw files.
She wanted an external viewer outside of Lightroom to preview her jpeg photos. Fastrawviewer should be the answer.

Comment: I don't want to view raw photos — I want to develop them to match the in-camera JPEG. Please read the question carefully.